# how to receive mail and send notification to the user in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-3.1, imap, scheduler

I have been trying to receive emails in rails using IMAP and send a notification to user that new mail has come. I have a table namely "email" where i have to store the email information like message_from, message_to, message and i wanted to know how to fetch the emails from the gmail whenever a new mail comes in. And the following is the code

```
  require 'net/imap'
  require 'net/http'

  imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com', 993, usessl = true, certs = nil, verify = false)
  imap.login('sampleuser', 'password')
  imap.select('INBOX')
  imap.search(["NOT", "SEEN"]).each do |message_id|
    emails = imap.fetch(mail,'RFC822')[0].attr['RFC822']
    @mail = Email.new("from" => emails.from, "to" => emails.to)
    @mail.save
  end
```

but i cannot able to fetch the message_from or message_to or the message, it shows error as

```
TypeError (can't convert Symbol into Integer):
```

how can i get those details and i want to send notification to the user when a new entry is created in the table and clicking on that should take it to the page where i have to display the email.

How can i do this and should i be using something like scheduler to check if the new mail has come and if i am not reading the mail how can i identify that i have received the mail already and i do not want to duplicate. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet on receiving emails is [Griddler](http://github.com/thoughtbot/griddler). [It's easy to setup](http://blog.shivamdaryanani.com/blog/2013/11/07/receiving-email-in-a-rails-app/)

You can send the email to the model you want and do the processing there.